# Обращение к дочернему элементу NodeList'а

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

Предположим имеется сильно вложенная HTML-структура с элементами, идентифицируемыми классами:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="parent1">
    <div class="abc-001">
        <div class="cde-002">
            <div class="xyz-003">
                    ...<div class="opl-999">
                       </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Необходимо обратиться к самому последнему элементу "opl-999".
На ум приходит свойство [childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp), но при попытке обратиться с данным свойством к методу [getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

```
With WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Navigate link      
    Set objChild = .document.getElementsByClassName("parent1").childNodes[998]
End With
```

выдается ошибка о том, что свойство это отсутствует. Аналогичная ситуация и со свойством [firstChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp)

```
Set objChild = .document.getElementsByClassName("parent1").FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild '...повторяем много раз...' .FirstChild
```

Cуществуют ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты решения проблемы, не меняя при этом исходную задачу и не отходя от DOM?

Comment: если рассматривать dom как дерево, то тебе нужен обычный [поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: @Grundy, да ну нафиг! Надо просто понять почему вышеобозначенное не срабатывает...

Comment: Не срабатывает хотя бы потому, что _getElementsByClassName_ возвращает коллекцию, а у коллекций нет свойств FirstChild или childNodes. Эти свойства есть у _конкретной_ ноды.

Comment: @Grundy, те же яйца: `Set objChild = .document.getElementsByClassName("parent1")(0).childNodes[998]`

Comment: Какая ошибка стала? childNodes - это коллекция непосредственных детей. Для примера из вопроса в этой коллекции будет один элемент

Comment: Не знает такого свойства.

Comment: проверь какие свойства есть у полученного объекта, возможно в VBScript важен регистр и свойство начинается с большой буквы. а не с маленькой, как в javascript

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77172/discussion-between-the-immortal-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что свойства *[FirstChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp)*, *[childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)* применимы к **конкретному** *[Node](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)* (элементу), а не к коллекции *[NodeList](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp)*, которая возвращается после вызова метода [getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp) без указания в параметрах номера конкретного узла:

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of an element's child elements with the specified class name, as a *NodeList
>   object*.
>   The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The *nodes* can be
>   accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Таким образом, после указания искомого класса, необходимо задать номер конкретного узла, а далее воспользоваться вышеуказанными свойствами. Например:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].FirstChild;
```

В случае VBScript номер узла указывается в круглых скобках:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("example")(0).FirstChild
```